# $emit and $on strange behavior - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can't read information in a Vue documentation about emitting an event to a parent non traditional way, using `$on`:

Child component:

```
this.$parent.$emit('loader', value)
```

Parent component (where i do import a child component):

```
this.$on('loader', (value) => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

Notice, it works only if i use `this.$parent.$emit` in a child component, why it doesn't work without `$parent`?

If i use it in a usual way in a parent component:

```
<child-component @loader="callMethod"/>
```

It does work with `this.$emit` without `$parent`. Could someone explain?

Also i can use `this.$root.$emit` and `this.$root.$on` respectively. So confusing.

**UPDATE1**

Reading the docs again, regards `$on` on this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on), i came to understanding, that `$on` and `$emit` should be used within the same Vue instance, hence it requires `this.$parent` i guess?

Comment: you should do only `this.$emit('loader', value)` and you don't need `$on` in parent component

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, but why?

Comment: This is not answering my question. There's obviously 2 ways to emit the event from a child to a parent, why `$on` does work only if i `this.$parent.$emit`? When i use `this.$emit`, vue-devtools is showing child-component as emitter, but when i use `this.$parent.$emit` it shows parent-component. What's the purpose of `$on` then?

Comment: it's bizarre, i test it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3xv22ojwl) and i got the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have two components A <- B <- C. `A` is a parent of `B` and `B` is of `C`.

When you use this in component `C` - `this.$parent.$emit('loader', value)`, what you are actually doing is - raise an event from component `B` which can be then used by component `A` in its template. So the following will work:

```
<template>
    <!-- A.vue COMPONENT -->
    <div>
        <!-- Component A doesn't know if event raised by B or C -->
        <!-- Component A only sees component B -->
        <B @loader="doSomething($event)">
    </div>
</template>



<script>
    // C.vue COMPONENT
    export default {

        mounted() {
            const compB = this.$parent;

            // It means event is raised on behalf of component B by component C.
            compB.$emit('loader', someValue);
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you are familiar with Node.js, then every Vue component behaves like an `EventEmitter` or `EventBus`. So it can listen to its own events like:

```
// some-vue-compoennt.vue
<script>
    export default {

        mounted() {

            // LISTEN TO OWN EVENTS
            this.$on('my-own-event', () => console.log('Listening to myself'));

            // After some time
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.$emit('my-own-event', someValue);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Usage - Almost Never:

As far as the usage is concerned, you should not use `$parent` instance directly. Always adhere to `prop` and `event` model for parent-child communication. It is used internally by Vue and only when in certain specialized scenarios like Graphs, Maps related components where grandchildren components need to access data. It created a tight coupling between parent and children. It can also be used when you are programmatically creating orthogonal components like alerts, snackbars, dialogs, etc.

`$root` is typically used to broadcast events or signal. It is sometimes used to handle or access singleton data. But again consider using `Redux` or `Vuex` for this purpose. This solution based on `$root` doesn't scale really well